# C++, полиморфизм и умные указатели

Tags: c++, указатели, полиморфизм, smart, shared-ptr

Я плохо понимаю, как умные указатели (особенно `shared_ptr`) взаимодействуют с полиморфными типами. Общая картина кажется простой, но как только я начинаю разбираться в деталях, то просто тону в них.

Например, я не совсем уверен в том, что именно происходит "под капотом" в следующем коде:

```
shared_ptr<Base> get()
{
    return make_shared<Derived>();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    shared_ptr<Base> base = get();
    return 0;
}
```

Особенное непонимание вызывают ситуации, когда через указатель на базовый класс нужно попытаться достать объект производного класса (юнит-тесты и другие ситуации).

В случае с сырыми указателями или ссылками все тривиально:

```
void do_something(Base* base)
{
    Derived *derived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base);
    if (derived != nullptr)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Но в случае с умными указателями (особенно, разделяемыми `shared_ptr`) все становится сложно, потому что это шаблонные классы, которые нековариантны.

Мне непонятно, чем отличается:

```
shared_ptr<Base> base = make_shared<Derived>();
```

И:

```
shared_ptr<Derived> base = make_shared<Derived>();
```

Также мне интересно, законно ли это, и есть ли тут потенциальные проблемы:

```
void do_something(shared_ptr<Base> base)
{
    // Принято ли так делать?
    Derived *derived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base.get());
    if (derived != nullptr)
    {
        // ...
  }
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Base> base = make_shared<Derived>();

    do_something(base);
}
```

Comment: `shared_ptr<Derived>` неявно приводится к `shared_ptr<Base>`, соответственно под капотом там будет либо `Derived*`, либо `Base*`. По поводу приведения - да, законно. Есть ещё `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, который служит для приведения любых типов указателей (хоть `T*`, хоть `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: Добавлю лишь, что после получения сырого указателя вы сами должны следить за тем, чтобы умный указатель, который им владеет, не удалил объект, на который ссылается этот самый  указатель.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Умный указатель - это указатель, который умеет сам вызывать `delete` объекту.

Отсюда сразу следует два свойства:

1. никогда нельзя вызывать delete объекту самостоятельно, если им владеет умный указатель;
2. никогда нельзя создавать умный указатель на объект, которым уже владеет другой умный указатель.

Если же говорить о том что с ним *можно* делать - ответ будет "смотри его интерфейс".

Конкретно в случае `shared_ptr` вы можете делать с умным указателем почти всё что можно делать с указателем обычным: его можно копировать, приводить к указателю на базовый тип, также ему можно делать все 4 приведения типа через специальные функции ([`std::static_pointer_cast`, `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, `std::const_pointer_cast` и `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)).

Также всегда можно получить сырой указатель через метод `get()`, и далее делать с ним что угодно кроме вызова delete. Но так поступать не рекомендуется: если вы широко используете умные указатели, то сырой указатель можно случайно "обернуть" в умный, что приведет к вызову delete.

Comment: никогда нельзя создавать умный указатель на объект, которым уже владеет другой умный указатель?  Абсолютно несогласен

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а более конкретных возражений не будет?

Comment: std::shared_ptr какраз используется тогда, когда вы хотите ссылаться на ваш объект из нескольких мест

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, нельзя создавать новый умный указатель с нуля, если указателем уже владение другой умный указатель. Только копировать текущий.

Comment: @MrBin, ясно, значит я неправильно понел что имелось ввиду